# Post Request with strings.NewReader Containing Escape Sequence

Tags: json, rest, http, go

I'm trying to retrieve a response from a POST endpoint which accepts a payload.

For `curl` request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://api.io/v1/oauth/token \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{
      "userToken": "myemail@domain.com:MyUserProfileToken"
    }'
```

I can do this with:

```
func GetJWT() string {

    endpoint := "https://api.io/v1/oauth/token"

    payload := strings.NewReader(`{
      "userToken":"myemail@domain.com:MyUserProfileToken"
}`)

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint, payload)

    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    return string(body)
}
```

and

```
    payload := strings.NewReader("{\n  \"userToken\": \"myemail@domain.com:MyUserProfileToken\"\n}")
```

However, when I try to pass string pointers for email and token, and declare the payload like

```
func GetJWT(userEmail, userToken *string) string {

    endpoint := "https://api.io/v1/oauth/token"

    payload := strings.NewReader("{\n  \"userToken\": \*userEmail\":\"\*userToken\n}")

    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", endpoint, payload)

    req.Header.Add("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

    res, _ := http.DefaultClient.Do(req)

    defer res.Body.Close()
    body, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(res.Body)

    return string(body)
}
```

an error is returned for unknown escape (column 53 on payload declaration).

How can I escape string pointers so that I can concatenate `userEmail`, ":", and `userToken`

Comment: I see a couple problems here. First: I think the "unknown escape" is caused by `\*` since `\*` is not a legitimate escape character. Second: Golang does not support string interpolation. So the `userEmail` and `userToken` variables are actually never used in your `GetJWT` function. You can format variables into a string using `Sprintf` from the standard library `fmt` package.

Comment: Use `+` to concatenate the five strings: `"{\n  \"userToken\": \"" + *userEmail + ":" + *userToken + "\"\n}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple problems here.

First: I think the "unknown escape" error message is caused by `\*` since `\*` is not a legitimate escape character.

Second: Golang does not support string interpolation. So the `userEmail` and `userToken` variables are actually never used in your `GetJWT` function.

You can format variables into a string using `Sprintf` from the standard library `fmt` package. That would look like this:

```
fmt.Sprintf("{\n  \"userToken\" : \"%s:%s\" \n}", *userEmail, *userToken)
```